# Chart dates unevenly spaced on axis with lots of data

Tags: chart.js

[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdyzu.png)

Hey guys, I'm having a problem: as you can see in the screenshot, there are some resolutions that the distance between the last and the second to last dates on x-axis is greater than other ones when you use a lot of data on that axis. Can somebody with a project like that test to see if this happens to every project? Probably this is the way Chart.js handles putting more elements on x-axis, but can I do something about it?

Thank you very much!